# Artwork label (Artist.cpp Isn't printing)

Tags: c++

main.cpp

```
#include "Artist.h"
#include "Artwork.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string userTitle, userArtistName;
   int yearCreated, userBirthYear, userDeathYear;

   getline(cin, userArtistName);
   getline(cin, userTitle);
   cin >> userBirthYear;
   cin >> userDeathYear;
   cin >> yearCreated;

   Artist userArtist =  Artist(userArtistName, userBirthYear, userDeathYear);

   Artwork newArtwork = Artwork(userTitle, yearCreated, userArtist);

   newArtwork.PrintInfo();
}
```

Artwork.cpp

```
#include "Artwork.h"
#include <iostream>

// TODO: Define default constructor
Artwork::Artwork(){
title = "Unknown";
yearCreated = -1;
}

// TODO: Define second constructor to initialize
//       private fields (title, yearCreated, artist)
Artwork::Artwork(string title, int yearCreated, Artist artist){
this->title = title;
this->yearCreated = yearCreated;
this->artist = artist;
}
// TODO: Define get functions: GetTitle(), GetYearCreated()
string Artwork::GetTitle(){
   return title;
}
int Artwork::GetYearCreated(){
   return yearCreated;
}
// TODO: Define PrintInfo() function
//       Call the PrintInfo() function in the Artist class to print an artist's information  
void Artwork::PrintInfo(){
cout << "Title: " << title << ", " << yearCreated<< endl;
}
```

Artwork.h

```
#ifndef ARTWORKH
#define ARTWORKH

#include "Artist.h"

class Artwork{
   public:
      Artwork();

      Artwork(string title, int yearCreated, Artist artist);

      string GetTitle();

      int GetYearCreated();

      void PrintInfo();
   
   private:
      // TODO: Declare private data members - title, yearCreated
      string title;
      int yearCreated;

      // TODO: Declare private data member artist of type Artist
      Artist artist;
};

#endif
```

Artist.h

```
#ifndef ARTISTH
#define ARTISTH

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Artist{
   public:
      Artist();

      Artist(string artistName, int birthYear, int deathYear);

      string GetName() const;

      int GetBirthYear() const;

      int GetDeathYear() const;

      void PrintInfo() const;
   
   private:
      // TODO: Declare private data members - artistName, birthYear, deathYear
      string artistName;
      int birthYear;
      int deathYear;

};

#endif
```

Artist.cpp

```
#include "Artist.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// TODO: Define default constructor
Artist::Artist(){
   artistName = "Unknown";
   birthYear = -1;
   deathYear = -1;
}
// TODO: Define second constructor to initialize
//private fields (artistName, birthYear, deathYear)
Artist::Artist(string artistName, int birthYear, int deathYear){
   this->artistName = artistName;
   this->birthYear = birthYear;
   this->deathYear = deathYear;
}


// TODO: Define get functions: GetName(), GetBirthYear(), GetDeathYear()
string Artist::GetName() const{
return artistName;
}
int Artist::GetBirthYear()const {
return birthYear;
}
int Artist::GetDeathYear() const{
return deathYear;
}
// TODO: Define PrintInfo() function
void Artist::PrintInfo() const{
if( birthYear >=0 && deathYear == -1){
   
cout << "Artist: " << artistName << "(" << birthYear << "to present"<< ")"<< endl;
}

else if(birthYear >=0 && deathYear >=0){
cout << "Artist: " << artistName << "(" << birthYear << "to " << deathYear << ")"<< endl;
}
else{
cout << "Artist: " << artistName << " (" << "unknown" << ")"<< endl;
}
}
```

Given main(), complete the `Artist` class (in files Artist.h and Artist.cpp) with constructors to initialize an artist's information, get member functions, and a PrintInfo() member function. The default constructor should initialize the artist's name to "unknown" and the years of birth and death to -1. PrintInfo() displays "Artist:", then a space, then the artist's name, then another space, then the birth and death dates in one of three formats:

- `(XXXX to YYYY)` if both the birth and death years are nonnegative
- `(XXXX to present)` if the birth year is nonnegative and the death year is negative
- `(unknown)` otherwise

Complete the `Artwork` class (in files Artwork.h and Artwork.cpp) with constructors to initialize an artwork's information, get member functions, and a PrintInfo() member function. The default constructor should initialize the title to "unknown", the year created to -1. PrintInfo() displays an artist's information by calling the PrintInfo() function in the `Artist` class, followed by the artwork's title and the year created. Declare a private field of type `Artist` in the `Artwork` class.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Pablo Picasso
Three Musicians
1881
1973
1921
```

1881 and 1973 being the birth and death years respectively, with 1921 being the year the work was created, the output is:

```
Artist: Pablo Picasso (1881 to 1973)
Title: Three Musicians, 1921
```

My issue Is when I test this input I only get... (in a different .h file)

```
Title: Distant Muses, 2000
```

I was wondering why void Artist::PrintInfo() wont output anything and would be great if anyone could guide me to the right direction!

Thank You in advance!
[image]

Comment: Please show the `Artwork` class as well as the input for which you are getting unexpected result

Comment: Nothing is calling the function to print the artist. What do you think should call it? Then put the call there.

Comment: @GabrielZuniga, `void Artwork::PrintInfo()` doesn't call `PrintInfo()` method of `artist` member

Comment: @kuro could you elaborate? I'm not quite understanding.

Comment: Just copied the artist.h and artist functions to my cpp file, it does print actually. Might be linking error, not sure how it works in details.

P.S: Now looking to main.cpp, as others mentioned, you are not invoking `Artist::PrintInfo()`, therefore there is not output.

Comment: As @JHBonarius said. You are not calling `Artist::PrintInfo()` anywhere in your code and that is why you are not seeing that output.

Comment: @Alexsen it works on your end with no changes? I have no idea why It isn't linking on my end.

Comment: Seriously: the TODO comment (provided to you) above `Artwork::PrintInfo` literally says "Call the PrintInfo() function in the Artist class to print an artist's information". What's difficult to understand about it?

Comment: @GabrielZuniga You aren't calling `PrintInfo()` on your end. In your main.cpp you do not have `userArtist.PrintInfo()` to invoke `Artist::PrintInfo()`

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry man, I didn't see the comment. I'm running off a few hours of sleep and caffeine. Spare me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through description, your `Artwork` class should contain `PrintInfo()` method, which on it's own should call `Artist::PrintInfo()` once invoked. Add printing the artist info before printing it's own info in the `Artwork::PrintInfo()` method and you should be good to go. It should look like this:

```
void Artwork::PrintInfo(){
    artist.Printinfo(); // Not 100% sure this is correct syntax, check carefully.
    cout << "Title: " << title << ", " << yearCreated<< endl;
}
```

Also, worth noting that you can 'merge' constructors. Instead of this(Yes I'm aware it's 'required', but you can take a step further):

```
Artist::Artist(){
   artistName = "Unknown";
   birthYear = -1;
   deathYear = -1;
}
// TODO: Define second constructor to initialize
//private fields (artistName, birthYear, deathYear)
Artist::Artist(string artistName, int birthYear, int deathYear){
   this->artistName = artistName;
   this->birthYear = birthYear;
   this->deathYear = deathYear;
}
```

You can have this:

```
Artist::Artist(string artistName="Unknown", int birthYear=-1, int deathYear=-1){
   this->artistName = artistName;
   this->birthYear = birthYear;
   this->deathYear = deathYear;
}
```

By setting default values, if constructor isn't provided any value, aka default constructor is used, everything will be set to default value, in this case `"Unknown"` and `-1`'s. If someone provides name, you will have name and `-1`'s and so on.

Comment: I am not allowed to edit main.cpp

Comment: @GabrielZuniga In this case, there is only one way(as far as I'm aware) to print the info - To invoke the function in the class itself. Once constructor is called, you can force it to print info as well, although I don't think this is the best/correct way.

Comment: This is hurting my brain. Could you elaborate on how to force a print without using main.cpp.

Comment: @GabrielZuniga You can call the `PrintInfo()` method right in your constructor. IMO just adding `this->PrintInfo()` shall invoke the function. Note that it should be done at the end, after provided info is set. Although, this might need to be played a little around, I haven't called a method inside constructor for quite a while.

Comment: Also please note that I hardly doubt this is a 'normal' way to do it, since just creating an instance will already print the info.

Also, your task is to create `Artist::PrintInfo()` method. Your method is working, and is doing it's job correctly. it's not necessary to print if the author doesn't want to print. Your task to implement the method is already done. Also, note that at one point you are missing a space somewhere at `'to'` while calling info.

Comment: Maybe instead of calling `Artist::PrintInfo` from `Artist::Artist`, you're supposed to call it from `Artwork::PrintInfo`, since an `Artwork` contains an `Artist` as a data member.

Comment: @NathanPierson That's pretty correct reading the whole task now. Will update the asnwer

Comment: Pretty explicitly, actually: "PrintInfo() displays an artist's information by calling the PrintInfo() function in the Artist class, followed by the artwork's title and the year created."

Comment: It might not be the normal way, but its the only way my eTextbook allows me to complete it. I've defined the method but since I can't use main, and I'm quite unexperienced, I really do not know the workaround.

Comment: @GabrielZuniga Took summary from these comments as well, since I haven't read your post top-to-bottom after edited. Updated the answer corresponding to the new info, thanks to Nathan.

Comment: @Alexsen that was it. Thank you for showing me, I have troubles reading -> execution.

Comment: @GabrielZuniga if you aren't familiar with pointers in CPP, it might look weird. I will try to explain very briefly: `this.member` and `this->member` both indicate towards member. One accesses via value, another accesses via pointer but returns a value. This is a very brief and is missing quite a bit of details, but should give you a correct direction where to seek the answer.

Comment: Also, take all of those with a grain of salt, since I haven't dealt with a lot of OOP in CPP, you barely need it in Competitive Programming, but one thing I remember is I was using `this->member` or should I say `node->left` and `node->right` when node was a pointer type.